# MYSQL How to select value from other table that not exist

Tags: mysql

(If this title of question is wrong, someone please fix it ..)

I have three tables like this

```
TABLE SCHOOL

--------+--------+----
No. |NAME    |CLASS  |
--------+--------+----
1.  |Batman  |math   |
--------+--------+----
2.  |Batman  |biology|
--------+--------+----
4.  |Batman  |karate |
--------+--------+----
5.  |Superman|biology|
--------+--------+----
6.  |Superman|karate |
--------+--------+----
7.  |Superman|swim   |
--------+--------+----

TABLE SUPERHERO
--------+-----
No. |NAME    |
--------+-----
1.  |Batman  |
--------+-----
2.  |Superman|
--------+-----

TABLE CLASS

--------+-----
No. |CLASS   |
--------+-----
1.  |Math    |
--------+-----
2.  |biology |
--------+-----
3.  |karate  |
--------+-----
4.  |Swim    |
--------+-----
```

The Question is : How to select that batman did not take swim class, and superman did not take math class ?
like this :

```
(Output table that I want)
+--------+-------+
|NAME    |CLASS  |
+--------+-------+
|Batman  |swim   |
+--------+-------+
|Superman|math   |
+--------+-------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `CROSS JOIN` `SUPERHERO` and `CLASS` table first in order to get all possible combination of `SUPERHERO & CLASS`.

Later make a left join between the above cross joined table `t` and `SCHOOL` table.

Finally filtering the results in the `WHERE` clause by checking corresponding `SCHOOL` entry to `NULL` ensures that those combinations (`superhero`,`class`) don't actually exist in `SCHOOL` table

```
SELECT 
 t.NAME,
 t.CLASS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
   SH.NAME,
   C.CLASS
  FROM SUPERHERO SH
  CROSS JOIN CLASS C 
) AS t 
LEFT JOIN SCHOOL S ON t.NAME = S.NAME AND t.CLASS = S.CLASS
WHERE S.NO IS NULL
```